# Python Tkinter : Assignment of A Matrix of Entry Boxes

Tags: python, matrix, tkinter

I created a matrix of entry boxes using Tkinter and Python 2.3. What I want to do is to check the row of the entry box for a keyword and then insert a text into an entry box with the same row but of different column. For example, take a simple 3x3 entry box matrix:

```
Food         Like         Dislike
Apple                       Yes 
Orange        Yes
```

Let's say I have two lists that corresponds to each other as such:

```
1. [Apple, Orange]
2. [Dislike, Like]
```

I would like to check that if first element in list 1 is Apple and first element in list 2 is Dislike, then I want to insert a text "YES" into the entry box of 2nd row and 3rd column as shown in the above matrix.

I have appended the entry box indexes into two lists. First list contains the indices of the 1st column of entry boxes. Second list contains the 2nd and 3rd columns of the entry boxes. Problem is, how to determine the correspoding row and column of the entry box to insert the Yes???

Hope you can understand! This example is the most elementary one. My actual matrix consist of more rows and columns. An idea or sample code will help a lot.

Thank you Tkinter Gods.

Answer (score 0):

Store references to the entry widgets in a dictionary of lists. Here's an example using the label as the key:

```
for item in list_of_things:
    label = tk.Label(...)
    column0 = tk.Entry(...)
    column1 = tk.Entry(...)
    matrix[label] = (column1, column2)
```

You can now get column1 of "Orange" with something like `matrix["Orange"][1]`